# Good practice for letting user search database table from search box in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a .NET Web Api that has a search method to a sql server. Users can search in a textbox and on every new entered character the searchmethod will be called and query the database and return the results from the table.

For instance: SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Table.Name like '%UserSearchText%'

My question to this is:

Do you know any good practices for this scenario, in terms of: should I try to cache the results(Don't have to get the updated results immediately instead it could be 10 seconds old for instance) or should I just query the db everytime even though in would result in a lot of queries being made?

Anyone else implemented this before? It seems like a common task therefore I figured there could be a few smart ways to do it. If you have any input or know about any blog posts or any help whatsoever, I would highly appreciate that. Thanks!

**EDIT**
Query should be SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Table.Name like 'UserSearchText%'

Comment: That's a *bad* practice. `LIKE '%abc%'` can't use any indexes on the column so it forces a full table scan. You wouldn't need any kind of caching if the query worked correctly. On the other hand `LIKE 'UserText%'` *does* take advantage of indexing. `Anyone else implemented this before? ` Every web developer since the 90s.

Comment: it depends on the requirements. it cannot be really real time in theory.

Comment: If you *do* want full-text search, use SQL Server's [Full Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search) indexing and operators like CONTAINS, FREETEXT

Comment: @LeiYang no-one requires "really real-time" in an auto-fill box. Using proper indexing or even full-text search is enough to create a responsive textbox. There's even built-in autocomplete support in various .NET controls

Comment: i don't see why full text search is needed. i'd agree auto-fill box does not need real time search

Comment: .NET combo controls already support autocomplete support in one way or another. You don't have to build your own implementation, just provide an efficient query

Comment: @LeiYang because without it you *can't* use indexing to search in the *middle* of a field. Prefix searches are essentially range searches, which is why they benefit from indexing. `LIKE 'ABC%'` is (roughly) equivalent to `BETWEEN 'ABC' and 'ABD'` which can be accelerated by an index on the search column.  `Like '%ABC%'` though requires scanning the entire table, unless a full-text index is used

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it seems like I can make a request to the db each time as long as the query is good. That was my main question, if people cache this or not.

Comment: seems no one is saying 'you can make a request to the db each time', and ' the query is good' seems to require Full Text Search

Comment: @LeiYang "You wouldn't need any kind of caching if the query worked correctly". "On the other hand LIKE 'UserText%' does take advantage of indexing". Was refering to that, I'll use that query instead with index, seems fine?

Comment: i'm not quite sure, sorry, suggest you ask himself or just try out the performance and see whether acceptable or not.